# Why $Z_p$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A_n=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ be a ring and $p$ is prime, $\phi_n: A_n\rightarrow A_{n-1}$ be a natural homomorphism (Elements of $A_{n}$ define in an obvious way elements of $A_{n-1}$).

Define $p-adic$ integers $Z_p = \varprojlim (A_n,\phi_n)$, whose elements are $(...,x_n...,x_1)$ with $x_n \in A_n$ and $\phi_n(x_n)=x_{n-1}$ if $n \geq 2.$ So $Z_p$ is a subring of $\prod A_n$.

> Give $A_n$ the discrete topology, $\prod A_n$ product topology, then $Z_p$ is closed in $\prod A_n$.

How to prove the above argument? Is any single element in $Z_p$ closed?

Comment: Yes, singletons are closed on $\prod A_i$. This is because the projection maps $\pi_n:\prod A_i \to A_n$ is continuous. So $\pi_n^{-1}(\{x_n\})$ is closed in $\prod A_i$. Now, if $(x_i)\in\prod A_i$, then $\{(x_i)\}= \bigcap_n \pi_n^{-1}(\{x_n\})$, the intersection of closed sets.

Comment: @RobertGreen Which is why it was a comment. Please keep up. This is the third time today somebody has 'corrected' a partial answer comment. Irritating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be the product, endowed with the product topology, and note $\pi_n : A \to \mathbf{Z}/p^n \mathbf{Z}$ for $n\geq 1$ the projection. It is continuous by definition of the product topology. Then $\mathbf{Z}_p = \cap_{n\in\mathbf{N}^{*}} \{x=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in A\;|\;\varphi_{n}(x_n) = x_{n-1}\} =$ $ \cap_{n\in\mathbf{N}^{*}} \{x=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in A\;|\;\varphi_{n}(\pi_n(x)) = \pi_{n-1}(x)\}$ and each $\{x=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in A\;|\;\varphi_{n}(\pi_n(x)) = \pi_{n-1}(x)\}$ is closed by continuity of the projection, and by continuity of the $\varphi_n$ (the latter are continuous, as the $\mathbf{Z}/p^n \mathbf{Z}$ have the discrete topology !). So $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is an intersection of closed subset of the product, and is therefore closed.

*Remark* : $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is compact : indeed, it is closed in $A$ which is product of compact sets (indeed, if finite set with the discrete topology is compact, and the $\mathbf{Z}/p^n \mathbf{Z}$ are finite and endowed with the discrete topology.) The non trivial thing is that a infinite product of compact (even finite discrete sets) is compact, the so-called Tychonoff theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Show that the complement is open.

In particular, if $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\in \prod A_i\setminus \mathbb Z_p$ if any only if for some $n$, $\phi_n(x_n)\neq x_{n-1}$.

So, for each pair $a\in A_n$, define $$U_{a} = \pi_n^{-1}(\{a\})\cap\pi_{n-1}^{-1}(A_{n-1}\setminus\{\phi_n(a)\})$$

This is open (since $\{a\}$is open in $A_n$ and $A_{n-1}\setminus\{\phi_n(a)\}$ in $A_{n-1}$.)

Define $U = \bigcup_aU_a$, where the union is taking over for all $a$ in all $A_n$.

It is open because it is the union of open sets.

Then show that $U=\prod A_i\setminus \mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: This is really far-fetched, closedness is directly provable.

Comment: This works pretty easily. Not sure why you'd use an insulting term like "far-fetched." Do you know what "far-fetched" means? @RobertGreen

Comment: Far-fetched: adjective
unlikely and unconvincing; implausible.
synonyms: improbable, unlikely, implausible, unconvincing, dubious, doubtful, incredible, unbelievable, unthinkable

Comment: I learned something, as I didn't want to be insulting at all ! Far-fetched is often used as translation to "tiré par les cheveux" in french, which mildly means "complicated". I just wanted to say that as closedness is directly and trivially provable, there is no need to show openess of the complement.

Comment: See http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/far-fetched/580067

Comment: "Far afield" is a better English terminology. It implies taking an excursion rather than the direct route.

Comment: Last question and I stop the off-topic : far afield is typically english from England or ?

Comment: I don't know, I'm American. By the way, atleast one of those those examples you linked to implies the same meaning I did. A "far-fetched alibi" is one that is not believable, not one that is overly elaborate.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the quid pro quo : since I'm a kid I'm using far-fetched as "a bit more than complicated". From now I'll switch to "far afield" !

Comment: There's probably a better English phrase. "Far afield" is certainly okay, but it came to mind when I saw your usage of "far-fetched," which struck me as odd, but I assumed you meant something else, so I looked for a similar phrase.